# Options Item Selected change background color when state pressed

Tags: android

I want to change my background color, when my menu item state is "pressed" like this in the image below:

[Exmaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txopW.png)

So how to achieve it?

My menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/detail_edit_item"
      android:title="@string/edit"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_white"
      app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/detail_delete_item"
      android:title="@string/delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white"
      app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: you can build custom view

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround which you can use:
For API level 11 or above you can use toolbar widget:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.myapplication.MainActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Titel"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

To use this toolbar you have to set NoActionBarTheme for your activity

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have just used an ImageButton with my custom delete buttons in this example, after that you can write you selector to handle button press as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/delete" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/delete" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/delete_not_selected"></item>
```

You can save this code under drawable folder as background_selector.xml and this should work fine. you can find both images below but delete_not_selected is not visible because it is of white color but you will still be able to download it by clicking on the right side of the delete button.

[image: delete]
[image: delete_not_selected]

Comment: How to position the ImageView at the end of the toolbar, you have to consider that i use a menu, and it has 2 items. This wont work :(. I cant position the imageview to overlap with my menu item. Need another way to do this.

Comment: User relative layout inside toolbar widget and add as many views as you want inside app bar.I have updated the answer too so you can have a better idea.